# How to use Talend to send a dynamic URL link

Tags: etl, talend

I'm trying to use Talend to get weather data by latitude and longitude.  I'm retrieving all the applicable latitude and longitude values and then I need to loop through these and create URL's that contain the latitude and longitude.  I was trying to use a tFileFetch to retrieve the response, but I can't see any way to pass in variables for latitude and longitude.  Does anyone know if there is a different component I should use?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I'll try.

In the URI field of the tFileFetch component you can add your output from the previous component for the lat long, for example:

"http://www.weather.com/weather/right-now?lat=" + lat + "&long=" + long

If I'm totally off, please provide more detail as to what you're looking for.

You could also use the tRest component to retrieve the response.

Comment: thats very interesting. Can you put expressions in any field then with talend?

Comment: not in any field, but most fields support java expressions. in order to determine what a field supports you could look at the documentation (select component in job and press f1) or you could look at the JET templates of the component in question in the folder e.g. /talend/plugins/*localprovider/tFileFetch/